# Help with NSDictionary allKeysForObject: with no success

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have been trying to get this to work for quite some time now and is somewhat running out of options. I am trying to use "allKeysForObject" to select all keys for a certain object.

This is test code to try to select the keys for a result. The objects in the dictionary is suppose to be numbers but when i want to display it i am using %@ to get the result, which for me indicate that this is not number.

I have been playing around to try to select the key with int, NSString (as in the code example) and used the allObject array to do the select but have not been able to succeed. As i am very new at this i am running out of option and have to reach out for help.

```
NSDictionary *playerResultInTheGame = [readCurrentGameDataFunction finalResultForCurrentGame];


NSLog(@"playerResultInTheGame: %@", playerResultInTheGame);

NSArray *allPlayers = [playerResultInTheGame allKeys];
NSArray *allObjects = [playerResultInTheGame allValues];

NSLog(@"allObjects: %@", allObjects);

NSMutableArray *myObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

allObjects = [allObjects sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"allObjects: %@", allObjects);


NSArray *xxxxx = [playerResultInTheGame allKeysForObject:@"1"];
NSLog(@"xxxxx: %@", xxxxx);
```

The result i get is:

> 2011-01-17 20:50:34.554 XX[11203:207] playerResultInTheGame: {
>       Barnspelare = 2;
>       Vuxenspelare = 1;
>   }
>   2011-01-17 20:50:34.554 XX[11203:207] allObjects: (
>       2,
>       1
>   )
>   2011-01-17 20:50:34.555 XX[11203:207] allObjects: (
>       1,
>       2
>   )
>   Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
>   2011-01-17 20:51:50.086 XX[11203:207] xxxxx: (
>   )
>   2011-01-17 20:52:24.523 XX[11203:207] allPlayers: (
>       Barnspelare,
>       Vuxenspelare
>   )

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is. Are you trying to store a list of players? It's seems like you are using an dictionary to do the job of an array.

Comment: I am trying to select the result for a player and then display the name + result after the game is finished.

Comment: Why dont you print allkeys too?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so if you have a list of players, as the keys, and their scores as objects, to get that list printed at all, you might do this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"player1", @"2", @"Player2", @"3", @"player3", nil];


    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"player1"]);

    NSString *key;
    for (key in dict) {
        NSLog(@"Player: %@, Result: %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
    }

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys are probably numbers rather than strings. Using an `int` is definitely wrong, because Cocoa collections cannot store `int`s. You have to use NSNumber. So use `[playerResultInTheGame allKeysForObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]`.